# skipping JSON data records based on inner array values- D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, visualization

My data is as follows.

```
        data=[  {"venue":"Foyer","values":[{"avg":996.8,"sessions":[{"minTime":0,"maxTime":599,"count":50},
                                                {"minTime":600,"maxTime":1199,"count":39},
                                                {"minTime":1800,"maxTime":2399,"count":43},
                                                {"minTime":2400,"maxTime":2999,"count":48}],"timestamp":1449360000},
                        {"avg":986.4,"sessions":[{"minTime":0,"maxTime":599,"count":152},
                                                 {"minTime":600,"maxTime":1199,"count":51},
                                                 {"minTime":1200,"maxTime":1799,"count":36},
                                                 {"minTime":1800,"maxTime":2399,"count":68},
                                                 {"minTime":3000,"maxTime":3599,"count":34}],"timestamp":1452540000}]},
                {"venue":"Venue1","values":[{"avg":996.8,"sessions":[{"minTime":0,"maxTime":599,"count":62},
                                                {"minTime":600,"maxTime":1199,"count":33},
                                                {"minTime":1800,"maxTime":2399,"count":37},
                                                {"minTime":2400,"maxTime":2999,"count":24}],"timestamp":1449360000},
                        {"avg":986.4,"sessions":[{"minTime":0,"maxTime":599,"count":34},
                                                 {"minTime":600,"maxTime":1199,"count":52},
                                                 {"minTime":1200,"maxTime":1799,"count":21},
                                                 {"minTime":1800,"maxTime":2399,"count":142},
                                                 {"minTime":3000,"maxTime":3599,"count":23}],"timestamp":1452540000}]},
                {"venue":"Venue2","values":[{"avg":996.8,"sessions":[{"minTime":0,"maxTime":599,"count":44},
                                                {"minTime":600,"maxTime":1199,"count":25},
                                                {"minTime":1800,"maxTime":2399,"count":34},
                                                {"minTime":2400,"maxTime":2999,"count":23}],"timestamp":1449360000},
                        {"avg":986.4,"sessions":[{"minTime":0,"maxTime":599,"count":31},
                                                 {"minTime":600,"maxTime":1199,"count":11},
                                                 {"minTime":1200,"maxTime":1799,"count":122},
                                                 {"minTime":1800,"maxTime":2399,"count":12},
                                                 {"minTime":3000,"maxTime":3599,"count": 3}],"timestamp":1452540000}]}]
```

I want to filter the records from "values" with a matching timestamp only. The entries in "values" for non matching timestamps should be filtered, but the output should be of the same structure of data,

Expected Output:

```
            [{"venue":"Foyer","values":[{"avg":996.8,"sessions":[{"minTime":0,"maxTime":599,"count":50},
                                    {"minTime":600,"maxTime":1199,"count":39},
                                    {"minTime":1800,"maxTime":2399,"count":43},
                                    {"minTime":2400,"maxTime":2999,"count":48}],"timestamp":1449360000}]},
            {"venue":"Venue1","values":[{"avg":996.8,"sessions":[{"minTime":0,"maxTime":599,"count":62},
                                    {"minTime":600,"maxTime":1199,"count":33},
                                    {"minTime":1800,"maxTime":2399,"count":37},
                                    {"minTime":2400,"maxTime":2999,"count":24}],"timestamp":1449360000}]},
            {"venue":"Venue2","values":[{"avg":996.8,"sessions":[{"minTime":0,"maxTime":599,"count":44},
                                    {"minTime":600,"maxTime":1199,"count":25},
                                    {"minTime":1800,"maxTime":2399,"count":34},
                                    {"minTime":2400,"maxTime":2999,"count":23}],"timestamp":1449360000}]}]
```

I have tried with the following code, but only last venue(venue2) is appeared.

Code:

```
                d3.json("Dwell.json", function(error,data){     
                data.forEach(function(a) {
                resultfilter={ "venue": a.venue, "values":a.values.filter(function (d) { return d.timestamp = 1449360000 }  ) }
                }) 
                document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(resultfilter) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're overwriting `resultfilter` at each run of the `forEach` call.
You probably want to instead do something like `resultfilter.push( <FILTER RESULT>)` in each `forEach` loop after first initializing the `resultfilter` array. Something like this:

```
resultfilter = [];
data.forEach(function(a) {
    resultfilter.push(...);
})
```

(Also, looks like the `data` object you copied has some issues. If it was not related to copy/pasting into this question, then give that a check too)

Answer (score 1):

Can streamline this by using `Array.prototype.map()`

```
 var  resultfilter = data.map(function(item) {
         item.values = item.values.filter(function(d) {
             return d.timestamp = 1449360000
         });
         return item;
 });
```